# Compare 2D array in python with condition

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I have the following categories of integers from 1-9:

cat: integers from 1 to 3

dog: integers from 4 to 6

snake: integers from 7 to 9

I have a list which looks something like this:

```
listA =[[2, 4, 5, 7],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 2, 5, 8], ...]
```

Note that there is no scenario where a number can comes twice in a row.
For example, [1, 1, 4, 5] won't exist.

I managed to create another list from it which looks like:

```
listB =  [[cat, dog, dog, snake], 
          [dog, dog, snake, snake], 
          [cat, cat, dog, snake], ...]
```

I want to know for each category the number of odd and even integers which appear.

For example, dog has 34 even integers and only 10 odd, cat has 24 even, 35 odd, snake has 13 even and 3 odd.

Any idea? Any suggestion of what I should do?

Comment: Does the row Index matter?

Comment: @lucianopaz Yes, but for other calculations. In this case that I have here, it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your list of integers to the animal names you could use a nested list-comprehension with dictionary lookup:

```
num_to_animal = {1: 'cat', 2: 'cat', 3: 'cat',
                 4: 'dog', 5: 'dog', 6: 'dog',
                 7: 'snake', 8: 'snake', 9: 'snake'}


listA =[[2, 4, 5, 7],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 2, 5, 8]]

listB = [[num_to_animal[val] for val in row] for row in listA]
listB
# [['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'snake'],
#  ['dog', 'dog', 'snake', 'snake'],
#  ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'snake']]
```

But you don't need that to compute the number of even/odd values for each category, you only need to check to which animal the value belongs and if it's even or odd. For this you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_even(val):
    return val % 2 == 0

cnts = Counter((num_to_animal[val], is_even(val)) for row in listA for val in row)
cnts
# Counter({('cat', False): 1,
#          ('cat', True): 2,
#          ('dog', False): 3,
#          ('dog', True): 2,
#          ('snake', False): 2,
#          ('snake', True): 2})
```

The `True` and `False` represent if it's even. This `Counter` can be used like any normal dictionary:

```
cnts[('dog', True)]
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a map function: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

So for your 2D array, you might do something like this to produce your listB:

```
listB = []
for row in listA:
    listB.append(list(map(lambda x: num_to_animal_str(x), row))
```

with a 'num_to_animal' function that converts numbers to animals according to your rules.

Comment: how does this answer the question? I don't see how you can get the number of even/odd integers for each category from this. As far as I understand it he already got the list of list converted to the "animals".

Comment: @Will uhm, I stated that I already figured out how to do listB

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NumPy, there are expressive idioms for these sort of comparisons. For example,

```
In [3]: arr = np.array(listA)
In [4]: np.sum((arr>3) & (arr<7) & (arr % 2))
Out[4]: 3  # three dogs with odd integer identifiers
```